# The specified SDK version [2.0.0] from global.json not found;

Tags: azure, web-deployment, asp.net-core-2.0

It was all working fine. Suddenly I am getting this error on azure while deploying the application.

> **The specified SDK version [2.0.0] from global.json [D:\home\site\repository\global.json] not found; install specified SDK
>   version\r\n\r\nDid you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install
>   dotnet SDK from: \r\n\r\n 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409\r\nD:\Program
>   Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\71.10313.3301\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
>   "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"**

The strange thing is I am not using global.json. I am using asp.net core 2.0.
Is there some new changes in azure.

Comment: If it is possible, remove all files from WebApp and republish it again. You could check whether it is helpful.

Comment: This just started appearing for us today. @TomSun which files to remove exactly? (ie: which directory/directories in Kudu?)

Comment: @Marchy. If possible, during publish the project please  [Remove additional files at destination]. Note: that will remove all files in the azure project. If is not helpful, you could create another SO thread with detail info. If there is reproduced code demo will be more help.

Comment: @TomSun we're deploying through Git hooks. We tried spinning up a new instance too but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Removing Global.json from my project fixed the issues.

Comment: This isn't a solution. This would likely make the project use the latest version of the SDK instead of the one your app is coded against.